# Open Graph is acting weird on my site

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Well I'm having an issue with Facebook's Open Graph.

I have a Wordpress blog and I'm creating the tags dynamically. The problem is, it's not recognizing the og:title and og:url until I go to check what the Scraper see's on the page. Once I do that. It recongnizes everything and works smoothly.

*But then I have to check the Scraper for every article I write.*

**Site:** http://www.elnacional.com.uy

**Article:** http://www.elnacional.com.uy/jugadores/renato-cesar-juvenil-puede-reemplazar-a-viudez/

**OG tags:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Renato Cesar, juvenil, puede Reemplazar a Viudez">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.elnacional.com.uy/jugadores/renato-cesar-juvenil-puede-reemplazar-a-viudez/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.elnacional.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Renato-Cesar-150x150.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="El Nacional">    
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100003007910982">
<meta property="og:description" content="La inclusión de Renato César en el equipo en la última práctica de Nacional sorprendió a todos, incluyendo al propio juvenil.">
```

**Sometimes, the Scraper will return this FOR ANY NEW ARTICLE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0.1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body><p></p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong. I changed the code so many times in a few hours and facebook needed time to accomodate this.
Everything has been working smoothly since.